Docker Compose: Unable to Add Files to Local Directory After Binding Volume (WSL Integration)
I'm using Docker Compose with WSL integration to develop a PHP application. I've defined a volume mount in my docker-compose.yml file that maps the local directory ./tap-and-stack to /var/www/html within the container.
The issue I'm facing is that I cannot directly add files to the local ./tap-and-stack directory machine. Any changes I make within the container at /var/www/html are reflected locally, but adding files directly to ./tap-and-stack seems to be restricted.
docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  php:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./dockerize/php/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./tap-and-stack:/var/www/html

My Question is:
How can I configure Docker Compose to allow adding files directly to the local ./tap-and-stack not just only in var/www/html directory while maintaining the volume mount functionality?

Ensure that the permissions on the ./tap-and-stack directory are set correctly to allow file creation and modification
